# How to substitute and replace on expression using hash with multi-character variables?

Tags: regex, perl, hashtable, substitution, string-substitution

My current script will take an expression, ex:

```
my $expression = '( a || b || c || ab || ca)';
```

and go through each boolean combination of inputs using sub/replace, like so:

```
my $keys = join '|', keys %stimhash;
$expression =~ s/($keys)\b/$stimhash{$1}/g;
```

In the above example, assuming:

```
a => 0, b => 1, c => 0
```

The expression should become:

```
( 0 || 1 || 0 || ab || ca )
```

This works great.

However, I would like to allow the variables (also in `%stimhash`) to contain a tag, `*.`

```
my $expression = '( a* || b* || c* || ca || ab )';
```

Also, printing the keys of the stimhash returns:

```
a*|b*|c*
```

It is not properly substituting/replacing with the extra special character, `*.`
It gives this warning:

```
Use of uninitialized value within `%stimhash` in substitution iterator
```

I tried using `quotemeta()` but did not have good results so far.
It will drop the values. An example after the substitution looks like:

```
( * || * || * || ca || ab )
```

instead of:

```
( 0 || 1 || 0 || ca || ab )
```

As you can see the `/b` is used to prevent partial substitutions. Sorting the keys by length does not solve the problem because some variables are not being replaced (`ca` and `ab` in above example).

Comment: Re "Not to mention my previous question was downvoted because I did not give someone an upvote for the wrong/incomplete answer." Very unlikely.

Comment: Re "there are clearly differences in the question asked", If you have fixes to make to your question, use the *edit* feature

Comment: @ikegami: "Very unlikely."  I am not in the habit of lying on programming forums.  The guy said 'I would recommend you upvote me for the answer and repost the question'.  When I did not he deleted his comments and downvoted it.

Comment: I didn't say you lied, I indicated I believed you are mistaken about the reason you were downvoted. Even if what you say it true, it only accounts for one of the downvotes.

Comment: Your problem is caused by `\b`. According to [`perldoc perlre`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html): "A word boundary (`\b`) is a spot between two characters that has a `\w` on one side of it and a `\W` on the other side of it (in either order), counting the
imaginary characters off the beginning and end of the string as matching a `\W`." `* ` (asterisk followed by space) is not a word boundary.

Comment: Thanks! I should have checked the documentation; I assumed word boundary existed between * and space.